# Display site UUID from module

Tags: 8, entities

Is it possible to display the site UUID on a Drupal 8 module?

Answer (score 3):

"display" is pretty ambiguous, but you can get the site UUID like so:

```
$uuid = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('uuid');
```

(depending on context, injecting the config.factory service would be preferable)

It's a string so rendering it will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

for you Drupal 8 site

```
drush config-get "system.site" uuid
```

or if you need to change it

```
drush config-get "system.site" uuid "number you want"
```